# Need help understanding Page generated python code

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I need to import and call a Tkinter gui from another tk gui and used Page to generate said windows. I need help understanding the structure and logic behind the function generated to import the module.

```
w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    Support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        top.geometry("600x450+650+150")
        top.title("New Toplevel")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        self.Label1 = tk.Label(top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.183, rely=0.156, height=56, width=382)
        self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Label''')
        self.Label1.configure(width=382)

        self.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top)
        self.Entry1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.556,height=34, relwidth=0.64)
        self.Entry1.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry1.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry1.configure(width=384)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Basically the parameters in this function

```
w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    Support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)
```

Comment: What, specifically, are you confused about?

Comment: what the parameters used in the create_Toplevel1 function do, and how I would go about importing that function to another program

Comment: @AraragiKoyomi: ***"parameters used***: The first on `root` should be clear, the others are passed to `Support(...` which you didn't show. Read [tutorial - more-on-modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)